# Trigger instance launch on inbound IP traffic on its interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS spot instances are started on pricing decrease, this can happen anytime of the day (or does not happen for many days, depending on the config), i'm looking for a similar way to start an instance when there's a **user** request, eg. http request/ssh connection ... etc

I'm willing to monitor inbound IP traffic to my elastic IPs (on my internet gateway), and if target instance is stopped then launch it, a kind of wake-on-inbound-traffic.

The monitoring can be in two ways:

1. Passive: mirror traffic, analyze it in offline with some libpcap-based tool and launch instances based on the capture analysis, the downside is the very early IP requests to that instance will timeout till it start and bootstrap.
2. Active: analyze inbound traffic inline (using libpcap-based tool as well) and start the target instance, redirect http requests to some "Please wait while warming your instance" till the instance get started.

Anyone thought of doing this ? any guidelines for doing it ?

thanks !

Comment: Scratch libpcap off your list.  There is no traffic that can be accessed on the AWS network in promiscuous mode.  The network is extremely clean -- there are no incoming broadcasts, not even ARPs for your instance, because the infrastructure knows exactly where everything is and doesn't have to find it.  Elastic IPs are technically bound to nothing when the instance they were attached to is stopped, because stopped instances are not actually mapped to any physical host. On start, a host is selected, EBS volume attachments are coordinated, and the instance boots on physically new hardware.

Comment: Amazon WorkSpaces is a virtual desktop solution that has an hourly charge option. When a machine is unused for a period, it hibernates and charging stops. Reconnecting via the WorkSpaces client causes the server to 'wake'.  [Hourly billing](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/08/amazon-workspaces-now-offers-hourly-billing/)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot very clear, and if i want to make the same approach on my nic ips ? is it the same as the elastic ones ?

Comment: There is no direct way to start an instance based on traffic "for" that instance.  I have come up with some ideas but they all feel quite [Goldbergian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg) and perhaps part of the problem is that it isn't clear what the machine's actual task is. Perhaps you could clarify.  Another potential problem is that machines on the Internet get probed and scanned all the time and it seems very unlikely you're going to realize the anticipated cost savings without additional hassle to perfect the "what counts as a trigger" logic.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot here's my target architecture (simplified for the sake of clarity):
My office ----[vpn]---- AWS VPC.

Forget about edge and elastic IPs, instances inside the VPC are accessed only from my office through vpn.

I have an intranet web portal which is not used all the time by collaborators, it can stay unused (no one query its web interface) for some time and what i'm trying to achieve is not to get taxed for those unused hours ...

If some one request the web portal then instance is started, it will stay running for the end of the day (business day).

Comment: It's a way to idle instances when they are not used. usage can be defined as "http access", or any other stuff like "ssh access" or even a ping.